# Websocket connection to AppSync: `com.amazon.coral.service.http#HttpNotFoundException`

Tags: javascript, websocket, aws-appsync

I'm trying to create a Websocket connection to AWS AppSync, but upon connection I receive the error

```
payload
: 
{errors: [{errorType: "com.amazon.coral.service.http#HttpNotFoundException", errorCode: 400}]}
type
: 
"connection_error"
```

```
let ws = undefined;

const url = 'wss://XXXX.appsync-realtime-api.YYYY.amazonaws.com/graphql';
const apikey = 'ZZZZ';

const api_header = {
  host: 'XXXX.appsync-realtime-api.YYYY.amazonaws.com',
  'x-api-key': apikey,
};

const payload = {}; // payload should be an empty JSON object

const base64_api_header = btoa(JSON.stringify(api_header));
const base64_payload = btoa(JSON.stringify(payload));

const appsync_url = url + '?header=' + base64_api_header + '&payload=' + base64_payload;

ws = new WebSocket(appsync_url, ['graphql-ws']);
```

Comment: This example code using WebSocker directly instead of trying to use graphql-ws or another graphql websocket transport library works and is the most straightforward example I have seen anywhere. Thanks. Crazy that the host in the header has to be for the non-websocket url. I didn't notice that until I saw the answer here either.

Answer (score 5):

Your *host* within the *api_header* is wrong. It should be

`host: 'XXXX.appsync-api.YYYY.amazonaws.com',`

Note: `appsync-api`, **not** `appsync-realtime-api`.

Comment: I get the same HttpNotFoundException, even when I have the correct host without "realtime" in it. Did you change anything else to make it work? In the AppSync docs, the "'sec-websocket-protocol': 'graphql-ws'" is not included in the JSON to be base64-encoded. Where did you see this?

Comment: @cjs1978 I removed the `sec-websocket-protocol` from the question. I inherited it from here: https://github.com/roshanlabh/php-appsync-consumer-example/blob/master/appsync-subscription.php#L30 I forgot to remove it while writing the question.

Comment: @cjs1978 It sounds like you're doing the same mistake I did in the question. use `wss:// ... appsync-realtime-api ...`.  Reference: See this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-websocket-client.html and search for `AWS AppSync real-time endpoint`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. No, I do not have the "realtime" in my host URI. This is the structure of the JSON that I encode into the "header" query param: `{"host":"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/graphql","x-api-key":"xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}` - trying to make it work in Postman to start with, but no luck, I get the `{"payload":{"errors":[{"errorType":"com.amazon.coral.service.http#HttpNotFoundException","errorCode":400}]},"type":"connection_error"}` every time.

Comment: Ok, got it now - I had clearly stared at this for too long. Removing the "graphql" and the "https://" from the "host" part of the JSON did the trick. So: `{"host":"xxxxx.appsync-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com","x-api-key":"xxx-xxxxx"}`. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: "*I had clearly stared at this for too long*": Feel you. In case you get subscriptions working, I'd appreciate a hint here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293606/websocket-with-appsync-error-unsupportedoperation-unknown-not-supported-throug

Comment: I did get subscriptions working (with Angular + Angular-Apollo, and AppSync as GraphQL backend). Will take a look at your question now. This comment on github helped me a lot: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/224#issuecomment-858526106