# Websocket with AppSync: Error UnsupportedOperation, unknown not supported through the realtime channel

Tags: javascript, websocket, aws-appsync

I'm trying to send a subscription over a Websocket connection to AppSync. But when I send the request, I get the error `{errorType: "UnsupportedOperation", message: "unknown not supported through the realtime channel"}`

Here's my test code (yes, a *little* messy :) ):

```
let ws = undefined;

const id = 'XXX';
const region = 'YYY';
const apikey = 'ZZZ';

const host = id + '.appsync-api.' + region + '.amazonaws.com';
const url = 'wss://' + id + '.appsync-realtime-api.' + region + '.amazonaws.com';
const httpUrl = 'https://' + host + '/graphql';

function openWebsocket(){
  const api_header = {
    host: host,
    'x-api-key': apikey,
  };
  // payload should be an empty JSON object
  const payload = {};

  const base64_api_header = btoa(JSON.stringify(api_header));
  const base64_payload = btoa(JSON.stringify(payload));

  const appsync_url = url + '?header=' + base64_api_header + '&payload=' + base64_payload;

  return new WebSocket(appsync_url, ['graphql-ws']);
}

function runWebsocket() {
  ws = openWebsocket();

  /**
   * Send request over websocket
   * (Convenience function)
   */
  const _send = (obj) => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
  };

  let initializingMode = true;
  ws.onopen = (e) => {
    // initialization phase start:
    _send({ type: 'connection_init' });
  };

  ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    if (initializingMode) {
      if (data.type == 'connection_ack') {
        // Acknowledge came, so we can start subscribing

        // try to subscribe
        {
          const query = {
            query: `subscription MySubscription {
              onCreateNotifications {
                creationTime
                userid
              }
            }`,
          };
          const queryStr = JSON.stringify(query);

          _send({
            id: localStorage.getItem(HeaderItems.idToken),
            type: 'start',
            payload: {
              data: queryStr,
            },
            authorization: {
              host: host,
              'x-api-key': apikey,
            },
          });
        }

        initializingMode = false;

        return;
      }
    }


  };
  
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put the "authorization" object inside an "extensions" property:

```
         _send({
            id: localStorage.getItem(HeaderItems.idToken),
            type: 'start',
            payload: {
              data: queryStr,
              extensions: { /* The authorization needs to be wrapped here */
                authorization: {
                  host: host,
                  'x-api-key': apikey,
                },
              }
            },
          });
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-websocket-client.html - search for "Example using a custom domain name".

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Just figured the same :D One correction though: `extensions` goes inside `payload`. Could you fix that so I can accept your answer? :)